# Delay when changing screen in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, delay

I'm new member in libGDX . i want delay screen when changing screen
Here my code

```
myStage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(1), Actions.run(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game,MYSCORE));
            }
        })));
```

But the game not change the screen which i want. It stop at current screen . sorry about my bad languge . How can I fix it. thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on when you want it to be done, you need to call:

```
myStage.act();
```

And an example to get the output your looking for would be:

```
if(player.isDead()) {
    myStage.act();
}
```

But note, this is not an effective way to transition screens.

Comment: thanks . i want to call dispose() method when change screen . where do I put "this.dispose() "? @Samich